# Ajax call back: Return variable as input value

Tags: ajax, forms, variables

After ajax call back I need to echo out a variable as value of hidden field.

**HTML**

```
<form ajax1>
<input name="Place" value="Milan">
<input name=submit onclick="return submitForm1()">
</form>

<form ajax2>
<input type="hidden" value="$place">
<input name="filter">
<input name=submit onclick="return submitForm2()">
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

**Ajax Call**

```
function submitForm1() {
var form1 = document.myform1;
var dataString1 = $(form2).serialize();
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url:'query.php',
cache: false,
data: dataString1,
success: function(data){
$('#results').html(data);
}
});
return false;
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?
$place= $_GET['Place']
//do stuffs
?>
```

It works perfectly, but now I need to add a function to echo out **$place** in value=" " of **form ajax2**

Any help appreciated

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do, I'm lost.

Comment: echo out $place in value="" of form number two as result of my ajax call back